# How to align the bottom of two left- and right aligned texts with bottom of parent container?

Tags: html, css

Imagine you have this:

```
<div class="parent_with_height200px">
  <div class="left">This is the left floated text, size 12px</div>
  <div class="right">This is the right floated text, size 40px</div>
</div>
```

How can I make the two texts "stand" on the bottom of the parent div having their baseline aligned with each other?

It's perfectly ok to change the css/html, it's the result I want.

Comment: You may use positioning (`bottom: 0`), but that depends on your layout.

Comment: Sorry, need to use flow layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As feeela says, using position is how you will accomplish this.

```
.parent_with_height200px {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    }

.left {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #999999;
    }

.right {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: #444444;
    }
```

See the output here: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GxYx8/)

Comment: Well, it's close and I can live with pixel positioning if a true flow layout is not able. I was trying to play with vertical-aligns but to no avail. Your solution also does not align the baseline of the font, it aligns the bottom of the text containers which is not the same thing. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/GxYx8/13

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this should be what you're looking for: [http://jsfiddle.net/GxYx8/23/](http://jsfiddle.net/GxYx8/23/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.right {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: And how do you recon this would align the contents of the two floats at the bottom of the parent container?